# How (x*w+x1*w1+...xn*wn+b) checks if the obtained value is the difference between (x) and (y)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

If you can change the value of the variable 'epoch' on line 27 from 10 to 300, and run the algorithm at 00:00:00 today (for example), you will see that all values ​​except the values ​​in the last line of the dataframe will be very close to the values ​​the algorithm is trying to predict.
In a real case, the last line of the dataframe that will be used to send buy and sell orders to the market, but as they will not be values ​​close to the real ones, the algorithm will not reach its objective.
This problem occurs on line 124 of the example algorithm because at 00:00:00 the value that will be used (y_test) has not yet peaked.
Based on what was passed (y_test), it will be correct, but it will not be the desired value, because for that I need to wait 24 hours until the last line of the dataframe becomes the penultimate one (00:00:00 of the next day ) so the algorithm can actually predict their values ​​correctly.
Having the same problem in the new last line of the dataframe.

```
#Import libraries and dependencies
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='3'
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM,Dropout,Dense,Activation
import keras
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error

#Configure dataframe visualization
pd.set_option('display.precision',8)

#Configure some parameters to be used later
symbol='BTCUSDT'
test_size=0.2
window_len=5
lstm_neurons=100
dropout=0.2
output_size=2
activ_func='linear'
loss='mse'
optimizer='adam'
metrics=['mae','accuracy']
epochs=10
batch_size=1
verbose=1
shuffle=True
validation_split=0.25

#Collect exchange data
def collect_data():
    endpoint='https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol='+symbol+'&interval=1d&limit=5000'
    res=requests.get(endpoint)

    #Organize exchange data
    l=[]
    for r in json.loads(res.content):
        k=[]
        k.append(int(str(r[0])[0:10]))
        for i in r[1:]:
            k.append(float(i))
        l.append(k)

    #Create dataframe with exchange data
    hist=pd.DataFrame(l,columns=['Time','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume','Closetime','Quotevolume','Trades','Takerbuyquotevolume','Takerbuyassetvolume','Ignore'])
    hist=hist.drop(['Ignore'],axis=1)

    #Index data by time
    hist=hist.set_index('Time')

    #Convert the date time string into a date time object
    hist.index=pd.to_datetime(hist.index,unit='s')
    return hist

#Select the columns to be predicted with the neural network
def select_target_columns():
    target_col=['Low','High']
    return target_col

#Split data into 80% for training and 20% for testing
def train_test_split(df):
    split_row=len(df)-int(test_size*len(df))
    train_data=df.iloc[:split_row]
    test_data=df.iloc[split_row:]
    return train_data,test_data

#Normalize data, change the values of numeric columns in the dataset to a common scale
def normalise_min_max(df):
    return(df-df.min())/(df.max()-df.min())

#Extract data from windows
def extract_window_data(df):
    tmp=df.copy()
    tmp=normalise_min_max(tmp)
    window_data=tmp.values
    return np.array(window_data)

#Prepare data in format to be later fed into the neural network, 80% for training and 20% for testing
def prepare_data(df,target_col):
    train_data,test_data=train_test_split(df)
    X0=train_data.drop(target_col,axis=1)
    X1=test_data.drop(target_col,axis=1)
    X_train=extract_window_data(X0)
    X_test=extract_window_data(X1)
    X_train=np.reshape(X_train,(X_train.shape[0],1,X_train.shape[1]))
    X_test=np.reshape(X_test,(X_test.shape[0],1,X_test.shape[1]))
    y_train=train_data[target_col].values
    y_test=test_data[target_col].values
    y_train=y_train/y_train
    y_test=y_test/y_test
    return test_data,X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test

#Build sequential model, to stack all layers (input, hidden and output).
#The neural network is composed of an LSTM layer followed by a 20% exclusion layer and a dense layer with linear activation function.
#Completed the model using Adam as the optimizer and mean squared error as the loss function.
def build_lstm_model(input_data):
    model=Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(lstm_neurons,input_shape=(input_data.shape[1],input_data.shape[2])))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(Dense(units=output_size))
    model.add(Activation(activ_func))
    model.compile(loss=loss,optimizer=optimizer,metrics=metrics,run_eagerly=False)
    return model

#Train model using x_train inputs and y_train labels
def train_model(model,X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test):
    print('\nNeural Network Training\n')
    history=model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=epochs,batch_size=batch_size,verbose=verbose,shuffle=shuffle,validation_split=validation_split)
    return model

#Measure the average magnitude of errors in a set of predictions, without regard to their direction.
#Is the test sample mean of the absolute differences between actual and predicted observations, where all individual differences are of equal weight.
def mae(model,X_test,y_test):
    preds=model.predict(X_test).squeeze()
    mean_absolute_error(preds,y_test)
    return preds

#Graphically represent actual and forecast prices
def graph(test,target_col,preds):
    targets=test[target_col]
    preds=test[target_col].values*preds
    preds=pd.DataFrame(index=targets.index,data=preds)
    return targets,preds

#Create a new dataframe
def create_new_dataframe(df,preds):
    new_df=pd.DataFrame({
    'Low':df['Low'],
    'Buy':preds[0],
    'High':df['High'],
    'Sell':preds[1],
    })
    for i in new_df.index:
        new_df['Buy'][i]='{:.2f}'.format(new_df['Buy'][i])
        new_df['Sell'][i]='{:.2f}'.format(new_df['Sell'][i])
    return new_df

#Call all functions
while True:
    hist=collect_data()
    target_col=select_target_columns()
    train,test=train_test_split(hist)
    test,X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=prepare_data(hist,target_col)
    model=build_lstm_model(X_train)
    model=train_model(model,X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test)
    preds=mae(model,X_test,y_test)
    targets,preds=graph(test,target_col,preds)
    new_df=create_new_dataframe(hist,preds)
    print('\n')
    print(new_df)
```

Comment: What doesn't make sense to me is your question. It's way too confusing. Try to be a bit more clear.

Comment: @Abhishek Prajapat I would like to get the final result by multiplying X_test by y_preds.
Not doing y_test by y_preds.

Comment: So let me clear this out. 1) You don't have any issue with the code. 2) The issue seems to be about "How to implement....". 3) You want your y_pred to be the percentage difference from y_test.

Comment: Distance or percentage difference between x_test and y_test does not make any sense, you need to think about this before asking for help here. as we only take programming questions and your is not one.

Comment: Again that makes no sense, where are you getting this? What makes you think that this y_preds is multiplied with y_test? This is not how neural network predictions are computed. You are not even considering that these multiplications make no sense due to dimensions being very different.

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy let's go to an example.
X_test = 'Open' (30000).
y_test = 'High' (35000).
y_preds = (1.0028571429).
y_preds (1.0028571429) * y_test = 'High' (35000) = final result (35100).
Note that in this example I needed the y_test itself to get an absolute value.

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy Suppose you want to use this algorithm to predict real-time prices on the stock market, further suppose you are using the forecast against the daily chart, ie at 00:00:00 hours of a day the chart will start, and the first and only record he will get and that won't change over the next 24 hours is 'Open', all the others will change throughout the day 'High', 'Low', 'Close ', 'Volume'.
Imagine that in this same example the 'High' is at 00:00:00 in (30500), but it will sometime over the next 24 hours reach the (35,000) that I used to illustrate the previous example.

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy So by default I would need to wait 24 hours to get the value of 'High' (35000) so that I can use y_test ('High' = 35000) * y_preds = (1.0028571429) = result (35100).
Summing up the problem.
y_preds * y_test = Result (not useful).
y_preds * X_test = Result (serves).

Comment: You keep talking about this multiplication between y_preds and y_test, but this only makes sense to you, not to other people. The example does not make anything clear. This is your own algorithm or method, not a standard one.

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy I believe the problem is in the way the verification is done (x*w+x1*w1+...xn*wn+b) at this point it is verified if the obtained value is close to (y), otherwise a change is made subtle in weights, and so on.
This problem consists of (x*w+x1*w1+...xn*wn+b) verifying if the obtained value is a difference between (x) and (y), otherwise a subtle change is made in the weights, and so on against.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you have to change your current target (y_train) to the percentage difference of x_train and y_train. Also, the -ve difference should carry the -ve sign and the +ve difference should carry the +ve so that they are different from the model's viewpoint. After that, you need to remove the last layer activation from the model so that the negative output doesn't get canceled out. Now train the model as x_train as inputs and percentage difference as targets.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, but I would still need to multiply y_test by y_pred to get a final result, which would be y_test itself after all.
I need X_test to be used for the multiplication by y_preds to get the final result, which would be the y_test.

Comment: At this point, I genuinely think that your concepts and understanding are a bit vague. The thing is simple. The model can predict something and it's y_pred buy you can't have y_test so I don't know what you want anymore. Try somewhere else.

Comment: I will have X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test to train the model until it achieves satisfactory results, then I will save this model.
Using the live model, I will only need the X_test, since it is already trained, but the y_test I would need to wait for the end of the day to get it, making the forecast unfeasible.

Comment: post this question on Data Stackexchange.